# Present an UIAlertController on top of everything and stay on top even if another view is pushed (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'm trying to implement a `UIAlertController` that is presented on top of the window and stays that way until the user closes it, even if the application attempts to push another view controller.

I've read those questions and answers:

- [ios - present UIAlertController on top of everything regardless of the view hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991450/ios-present-uialertcontroller-on-top-of-everything-regardless-of-the-view-hier)
- [Present ViewController on top of everything regardless of the view hierarchy in IOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296552/present-viewcontroller-on-top-of-everything-regardless-of-the-view-hierarchy-in)

And while in versions previous to iOS 13 the provided solutions worked like a charm, I'm stuck trying to solve this issue in iOS 13:

When I show the `UIAlertController`, it stays in top until another view controller gets pushed in the navigation stack. If this happens, the `UIAlertController` disappears.

```swift
func showHighPriorityNotification() {
    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title"), message: "Message"), preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Button"), style: .default))

    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        // Trying to get this functionality to work in iOS 13.
        if var topController = alertWindow.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            topController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            topController.present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        // This code works in iOS 12 and below, but NOT in iOS 13.
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In iOS13, is there some way to keep the `UIAlertController` on top and allow views to get pushed below it? As I've said, in previous versions this just works nicely.

Comment: why are you using #available(iOS 13, *)? the funcionality is the same for all of versions

Comment: @x-rw Check the linked questions, but basically Apple changed the `present` behaviour in iOS 13. I've been trying to solve the issue in the #available.

Comment: If you'd present the `alertController` in your `alertWindow`, does it show up and disappears almost instantly? If so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131996/every-uialertcontroller-disappear-automatically-before-user-responds-since-ios/58133993#58133993

Comment: You should make that an answer, @pepsy :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same implementation as you used in iOS 12 and below, but you must hold a strong reference to the window you are presenting the alert on.

In your current code - when running on iOS 13 - the `alertWindow` will be destroyed as soon as `showHighPriorityNotification` finishes, dismissing your alert. It can be fixed by holding a strong reference to the `alertWindow` somewhere else.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131996/every-uialertcontroller-disappear-automatically-before-user-responds-since-ios/58133993#58133993) for a way of implementing that.