Error when accessing share menu on Sandbox iOS
I'm running xcode v. 15.3,  Swift v. 5.10, testing on iPhone iOS v. 17.4.1
I have a strange error I keep experiencing when trying to implement simple share sheet functionality which would allow the user to share the stored image. I've spent 2 days trying to find a solution online with no luck.
At first I thought its a storage issue so I tried SwiftData, CoreData and File system storage with the same results.
click on a todo with an image, at the bottom click share icon.
A share sheet should be shown instead nothing is shown and I see the following error in logs
Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x302f410e0> (Domain: com.apple.country.carrier_2, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: /var/mobile/Library/CountryBundles/, Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access

Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)}>
(501) personaAttributesForPersonaType for type:0 failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction.}

Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x10582e800> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10301e800> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10301e800>) which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x10700ee00>.
connection invalidated

Full app code:
//
//  ToDosApp.swift
//  ToDos
//
//  Created by Tunde Adegoroye on 06/06/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct ToDosApp: App {

    @AppStorage("isFirstTimeLaunch") private var isFirstTimeLaunch: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(ItemsContainer.create(shouldCreateDefaults: &isFirstTimeLaunch))
    }
}

//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ToDos
//
//  Created by Tunde Adegoroye on 06/06/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import SwiftUIImageViewer

enum SortOption: String, CaseIterable {
    case title
    case date
    case category
}

extension SortOption {
    
    var systemImage: String {
        switch self {
        case .title:
            "textformat.size.larger"
        case .date:
            "calendar"
        case .category:
            "folder"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    @State private var searchQuery = ""
    @State private var showCreateCategory = false
    @State private var showCreateToDo = false
    @State private var toDoToEdit: Item?
    
    @State private var isImageViewerPresented = false
    
    @State private var selectedSortOption = SortOption.allCases.first!
    
    var filteredItems: [Item] {
        
        if searchQuery.isEmpty {
            return items.sort(on: selectedSortOption)
        }
        
        let filteredItems = items.compactMap { item in
            
            let titleContainsQuery = item.title.range(of: searchQuery,
                                                      options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            
            let categoryTitleContainsQuery = item.category?.title.range(of: searchQuery,
                                                                        options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            
            return (titleContainsQuery || categoryTitleContainsQuery) ? item : nil
        }
        
        return filteredItems.sort(on: selectedSortOption)
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredItems) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                
                                if item.isCritical {
                                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.3")
                                        .symbolVariant(.fill)
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .bold()
                                }
                                
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .bold()
                                
                                Text("\(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .shortened))")
                                    .font(.callout)
                                
                                if let category = item.category {
                                    Text(category.title)
                                        .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                                        .bold()
                                        .padding(.horizontal)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                                        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.1),
                                                    in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8,
                                                                         style: .continuous))
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    item.isCompleted.toggle()
                                }
                            } label: {
                                
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
                                    .foregroundStyle(item.isCompleted ? .green : .gray)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                            if let selectedPhotoData = item.image,
                               let uiImage = UIImage(data: selectedPhotoData) {
                                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 120)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10,
                                                                style: .continuous))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        isImageViewerPresented = true
                                    }
                                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isImageViewerPresented) {
                                        SwiftUIImageViewer(image: Image(uiImage: uiImage))
                                            .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                                                Button {
                                                    isImageViewerPresented = false
                                                } label: {
                                                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                                        .font(.headline)
                                                }
                                                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                                .tint(.purple)
                                                .padding()
                                            }
                                        
                                        Button(action: {
                                                                        shareImage(uiImage)
                                                                    }) {
                                                                        Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                                                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                                    }
                                                                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                                    }
                            }
                        
                    }
                    .swipeActions {
                        
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            
                            withAnimation {
                                modelContext.delete(item)
                            }
                            
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                            toDoToEdit = item
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                        }
                        .tint(.orange)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My To Do List")
            .animation(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.easeIn/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, value: filteredItems)
            .searchable(text: $searchQuery,
                        prompt: "Search for a to do or a category")
            .overlay {
                if filteredItems.isEmpty {
                    ContentUnavailableView.search
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $toDoToEdit,
                   onDismiss: {
                toDoToEdit = nil
            },
                   content: { editItem in
                NavigationStack {
                    UpdateToDoView(item: editItem)
                        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showCreateCategory,
                   content: {
                NavigationStack {
                    CreateCategoryView()
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showCreateToDo,
                   content: {
                NavigationStack {
                    CreateTodoView()
                }
            })
            .toolbar {
                
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button {
                        showCreateCategory.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    
                    Menu {
                        Picker("", selection: $selectedSortOption) {
                            ForEach(SortOption.allCases,
                                    id: \.rawValue) { option in
                                Label(option.rawValue.capitalized,
                                      systemImage: option.systemImage)
                                .tag(option)
                            }
                        }
                        .labelsHidden()
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                            .symbolVariant(.circle)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom,
                           alignment: .leading) {
                Button(action: {
                    showCreateToDo.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Label("New ToDo", systemImage: "plus")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding(8)
                        .background(.gray.opacity(0.1),
                                    in: Capsule())
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
                    
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
    private func shareImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)

        // Selecting the appropriate scene
        let targetScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                             .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
                             .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene }) as? UIWindowScene

        guard let rootViewController = targetScene?.windows
                                                 .first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?
                                                 .rootViewController else {
            return
        }

        // Present the activity controller
        rootViewController.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func delete(item: Item) {
        withAnimation {
            modelContext.delete(item)
        }
    }
}

private extension [Item] {
    
    func sort(on option: SortOption) -> [Item] {
        switch option {
        case .title:
            self.sorted(by: { $0.title < $1.title })
        case .date:
            self.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp })
        case .category:
            self.sorted(by: {
                guard let firstItemTitle = $0.category?.title,
                      let secondItemTitle = $1.category?.title else { return false }
                return firstItemTitle < secondItemTitle
            })
        }
    }
}


//
//  TodoView.swift
//  ToDos
//
//  Created by Tunde Adegoroye on 06/06/2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TodoView: View {
    
    let item: Item
    @State private var isShareSheetPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            if item.isCritical {
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.3")
                    .symbolVariant(.fill)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
            }

            Text(item.title)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
        
            Text("\(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                .font(.callout)
            
            
        }
        
    }
}


//
//  Item.swift
//  ToDos
//
//  Created by Tunde Adegoroye on 06/06/2023.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var title: String
    var timestamp: Date
    var isCritical: Bool
    var isCompleted: Bool

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Category.items)
    var category: Category?
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var image: Data?
    
    init(title: String = "",
         timestamp: Date = .now,
         isCritical: Bool = false,
         isCompleted: Bool = false) {
        self.title = title
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.isCritical = isCritical
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
}

extension Item {
    
    static var dummy: Item {
        .init(title: "Item 1",
              timestamp: .now,
              isCritical: true)
    }
}



// Present the activity controller
rootViewController.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
this line, can be updated, this answer u can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298599/833395

See my answer to this related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78456715/415025
